# C# : Array.Except, Getting the index the value had in the original array of the returned array

Tags: c#, arrays

In the following code, I have to compare two strings, but I have to keep the Index of the original array.
Is there a way to do that?

CODE :

```cs
        private dataStruct[] compare(string[] older, string[] new_str)
        {
            List <dataStruct> diff = new List<dataStruct>();

            foreach (var str in older.Except(new_str))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
            return diff.ToArray();
        }
```

Actual output :
line 1
line 3...

Expected output :
[1]=>line 1
[3]=>line 3...

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the index"? What is the diff? Show some example input and expected output, read [ask], provide a [mre].

Comment: Probably can't use a foreach in that case.

Comment: I am using it as a test (just to print the output), at the end, it won't be that

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A foreach desn't keep track of the index, that's what for loops are for.

I'd imagine it will result in something like this:

```
private static dataStruct[] compare(string[] older, string[] new_str)
{
     int length = older.Length > new_str.Length ? older.Length : new_str.Length;

     List<dataStruct> diff = new List<dataStruct>();

     for (int index = 1; index <= length; index++)
     {
         string oldItem = index < older.Length ? older[index].oldItem : "N/A";
         string newItem = index < new_str.Length ? new_str[index].oldItem : "N/A";
                
         if (oldItem != newItem)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ID = [{0}]\t=>\t Old : {1}\t new : {2}", index, oldItem,newItem));
             diff.Add(new dataStruct(index, oldItem, newItem));
         }
     }

     return diff.ToArray();
}

struct dataStruct
{
    public int index { get; }
    public string oldItem { get; }
    public string newItem { get; }

    public dataStruct(int index, string oldItem, string newItem)
    {
        this.index = index;
        this.oldItem = oldItem;
        this.newItem = newItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't output what the OP asked for. As a matter of fact it doesn't even have the same semantics as the OP's original code. I don't know why the OP accepted this answer.

Comment: Your'e totally right @Enigmativity, that is not exactly the OPs original code semantcs. Apologies for that. But it's likely the intended behavior looking at he untouched List<dataStruct> for return. Nice solution by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This does it nicely:

```
foreach ((var str, var n) in older.Select((x, n)=> (x, n)).Where(z => !new_str.Contains(z.x)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{n + 1}]=>{str}");
}
```

When I test with this code:

```
compare(new [] { "A", "B", "D", "C", "E" }, new [] { "B", "C", "E" });
```

I get:

```
[1]=>A
[3]=>D
```